# Difference between declaring IBoutlet depending on where it declare

Tags: objective-c, properties, iboutlet, declare

We can declare like this for IBOutlet. Can I know what is the difference/advantages between 1 and 2 declaring method style?

```
@interface CurrentJobDetailsVC ()
{
    IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segControl; // -> 1 
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segControl; // -> 2 

@end
```

Comment: @property is work as public object which can be accessed outside of class where inner outlet is consider as private objects which are not accessed outside of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is globally the same expect 2 differences:

1 - Declare an iVar.

- `IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segControl;` is equivalent to `__strong IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segControl;`
- You only have an iVar and you can access it using `[segControl someMethod]`.

2 - Declare it as a property

- You have a property `self.segControl` and you can use it like `[self.segControl someMethod]`
- You also have an iVar and you can use it like `[_segControl someMethod]`

Comment: Can i know what is difference between _segControl and self.segControl?

Comment: `_segControl` is an iVar(directly the variable) and `self.segControl` use the property. For example if you call `self.segControl = nil` this is equivalent to `[self setSegControl:nil]`, you use the setter synthesized by the compiler for the property, but you can use the first or the second when you invoke methods.

Comment: Thanks. :) I don't know when I shall use ivar or property.

Answer (score 0):

1 is not accessible from other classes otherwise 2 is accessible.
And 1 should be...

```
__weak IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segControl;
```

`@property` will be auto synthesized and make setter/getter automatically.